# Perspective skew

Tags: perspective

I am planing to create a 3D anaglyph image for a give 2D image.

For this I will consider given 2D image as left eye view and now I have to create right eye view.

I came to know that the perspective rotation, perspecive skew, perspective distortation etc,. will create ritht eye view.

Suppose in an image if some objectas are very much closer to the camera and some are very far to the camera then the image should be

```
original    -    result

|------|       /-------/
|      |      /       /
|      |     /       / 
|------|    /-------/
```

That is from the center, the upper part should rotate/skew towards right and lower part should rotate towards left.

And suppose in an image if some of the objects are some what away from the camera and some are very far 
then the transformation should be

```
original    -    result

|------ |       /-------/
|       |      /       /
|       |     |       |
|------ |     |-------|
```

Tha is only the upper part will rotate/skew towards right and lower part should as it is.

Can I find any transfromation matrix for such a perspective skew or rotation?

What is 4 point perspective rotation and how will it work?

Thanks in advance